# SQL Server 2019 on Linux Time Zone Problem

Tags: sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset, sql-server-2019, sql-server-linux

Why there are different results (offset should be +03:00):

```sql
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMEZONE() as [CURRENT_TIMEZONE()] , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()];
```

result is :

```
CURRENT_TIMEZONE()        SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
(UTC+03:00) Istanbul      2022-01-20 10:32:03.6897159 +02:00
```

linux time is :

```
       Local time: Thu 2022-01-20 11:32:07 +03
  Universal time: Thu 2022-01-20 08:32:07 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2022-01-20 08:32:07
       Time zone: Europe/Istanbul (+03, +0300)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: [From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) *"For SQL Managed Instance, return value is based on the time zone of the instance itself assigned during instance creation, not the time zone of the underlying operating system."*

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. where does time zone get During the creation of instance? Because during the creation time zone was same as now. And I also removed and reinstalled the instance, result is same.

Comment: Then I suggest you file a bug with Microsoft. `CURRENT_TIMEZONE` is a new function, there may be issues with it

Answer (score 0):

I realized SQL Server does not care Turkey adopted +03:00, does not use daylight saving and got a temporary solution. SQL Server does not work properly for Europe/Istanbul so I set Europe/Moscow same time zone with it.

1. timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Moscow
2. systemctl restart mssql-server

Problem is solved.

| **CURRENT_TIMEZONE() | SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()** |
| --- | --- |
| (UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg | 2022-02-02 17:39:04.6127420 +03:00 |

Comment: I have this problem at the moment with Asia/Tehran :( and there isn't any countries like us :)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75812412/sql-server-returning-wrong-timezone-info-for-iran-after-dst-stopped?noredirect=1#comment133748374_75812412