# SQL Server returning wrong timezone info for Iran after DST stopped

Tags: sql-server, docker, timezone

I am facing an issue with SQL Server and the Asia/Tehran timezone after Iran stopped observing Daylight Saving Time (DST). I am using SQL Server with Docker 2019-latest, and while the `date` command inside the container returns the correct time zone information, the `select getdate()` command in SQL Server is still returning the old DST timezone information for Iran.

I have tried running the following query to check the time zone information for Iran in SQL Server:

```
SELECT name, current_utc_offset, is_currently_dst
FROM sys.time_zone_info
WHERE name LIKE '%iran%'
```

It returns the following result:

```
Iran Standard Time +04:30 1
```

It seems that SQL Server is not properly updating the timezone information for Iran after DST has ended. This issue is causing a lot of problems in my application, and I need to find a solution for it.

Can anyone please suggest a workaround or solution for this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest that the underlying framework isn't (yet) aware that the timezone no longer observes DST, as both Azure and 2022 CU2 also states that it's currently observing DST.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do at the moment? I should wait for some hotfix?

Comment: You could raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I did here: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/819

Comment: That's for issues with the repo, not the product. From the [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker#readme): *"If you require support with a production related issue, then please raise a support incident with Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4343728/support-for-business)."*

Comment: Can you recommend any temporary fix or workaround that I can try until the issue is resolved?

Comment: You could, instead, use `SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'+03:30')`.

Comment: Have you tried updating the container?

Comment: @Charlieface, Yes I did.The container itself show is correctly showing the time. the main problem is with mssql which I explain it in the question.

Comment: And also it's weird that the value of `select CURRENT_TIMEZONE()` is `(UTC+03:30) Tehran`

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814284/daylight-saving-and-browsing-issue

Comment: Regrettably, it appears that no other country observes a time zone equivalent to UTC+03:30. This poses a challenging predicament.