# Daylight Saving and browsing issue for Iran time zone

Tags: windows, google-chrome, timezone

Daylight saving not observed by some countries such as Iran from March 2023 but Microsoft didn't release any update related to this change. Disabling daylight saving setting is useful for OS time but some web based applications don't show correct time. Is there any configuration on web browsers to disable daylight saving or disabling daylight saving on OS settings is not enough for that?
Should we do some other configurations?

Answer (score 4):

The time zone database on GitHub has received [this change](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/66b18d9835dda089d65349c86e7851c4f0746e09), but it seems not reflected in the current time zone definitions in the Windows registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
\Time Zones\Iran Standard Time\Dynamic DST
```

contains daylight saving time definitions from 2004 to 2024. Try deleting the ones for 2023 and 2024 (or set `LastEntry` to 2022 instead of 2024). Perhaps a restart is required for this to take effect.

But (unlike my Windows clock) my Chrome browser on Windows already displays the correct time in the following snippet:

```js
document.write(Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {
  timeZone: "Asia/Tehran",
  timeStyle: "long"
}).format(new Date()));
```

Comment: I've published a blog post about that: https://www.teimouri.net/iran-daylight-saving-on-march-2023/
Also new temporary time zone.
But Microsoft should release TZ updates with Windows monthly update.

Answer (score 3):

As we've checked with our colleagues, the issue would be resolved by updating web browser to latest version. Also I've published a post about whole Iran daylight saving changes in March 2023: https://www.teimouri.net/iran-daylight-saving-on-march-2023/,
Also we are waiting to Microsoft update.

Answer (score 0):

worked in windows 10 just by set "lastEntry" to 2022, but restart required, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by fixing the time zone Dynamic DST in Windows registry.
this solution also doesn't effect previous years, effectively resolving the issue altogether, as Microsoft would do it.
here's my C# code.
don't forget to restart after running the code.

```cs
        string keyName = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones\\Iran Standard Time\\Dynamic DST";
        string keyName2 = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Time Zones\\Iran Standard Time\\Dynamic DST";
        string lastEntryValueName = "LastEntry";

        //set last entry to 2023
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, lastEntryValueName, "2023", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        //set 2023 to disable DLS
        var val = "2e,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00";
        var data = val.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "2023", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
        //remove 2024
        var subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName2, true);
        if (subKey != null)
            subKey.DeleteValue("2024");
```