# after change tehran summer timezone instead of 4:30 to 3:30

Tags: node.js, npm, timezone, nestjs, yarnpkg

after change tehran summer timezone instead of 4:30 to 3:30 my app time dont change

updated the time server and tested "start": "TZ=Asia/Tehran nest start" but it had no effect

Comment: Please add the code, which you use, to your question.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Does this answer your question? [Daylight Saving and browsing issue for Iran time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814284/daylight-saving-and-browsing-issue-for-iran-time-zone)

Comment: no, i use centos @Heiko Theißen

Comment: The code is used in different places
My code is related to the backend sample:
var date = new Date().getTime(),
Date.now(),
even in using the winston module@Geshode